# How to open a specific file from a Go executable in Windows by clicking

Tags: windows, file, go, parameter-passing

I have a Go program from which I have built a Windows OS executable. This program just takes in command line arguments and prints them.

What I want to do is: in Windows, I want to click on a specific file (let's say a text file) and I want my Go executable to print the name of the file. I am not sure how Windows passes the name of the file to an executable.

So far, I have right-clicked on my text file > Open with > choose another program > Look for another program in my pc > selected my Go executable. But I am unsure about the next steps.

I want my Go executable to find the location of the text file and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows passes the file name to the executable in the arguments so in your case if you are opening the file named process.txt using

`process.txt > Open with > Choose another program > Look for another program in my pc > Selected my Go executable`

I assume that your Golang code would be following following.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    log.Println(os.Args[1:])
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

Output:

> [.../.../process.txt]

This sample program will open up a command prompt and display the arguments on the console which will contain the file name which is passed via `Open With`. Now you will have the file path which you can process in your program.